# Performance consideration looking up localized strings in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a ASP.NET MVC website that uses strongly typed resource class to look up strings for the selected language.

Does each look up require a round trip to the server or are all resources loaded at once?

Example:

```
<span>@Resource.Just @Resource.a @Resource.sample</span>
<span>@Resource.JustASample</span>
```

Is there a difference between those two examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference, everything, i.e. all view rendering, is done on a server side. Of course there will be a little performace difference because rendering engine has to look up 3 resources instaed of one, but this can be safely ignored because, again, it will be done on a server side.

To make sure this is actually true, you can use Firebug or Fiddler to examine markup that is sent from the server, and make sure all resourse strings are there already.